# PHP - Recommended Configuration for Magento2

Tags: magento2, php

I'm using php 7.0.17 and I was wondering if anyone would let me know what the recommended configuration for the php.ini file was. I would like to see the complete recommended php.ini file with all settings. I'm using magento 2.1.6 and I have been given various information from different people but here is my current configuration:

```
max_execution_time = 18000
max_input_time = 300
memory_limit = 50000M
precision = 14
output_buffering = 4096
zlib.output_compression = On
zlib.output_compression_level = -1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also following setting is necessary too.

```
always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
```

The PHP **always_populate_raw_post_data** setting will let PHP always populate the $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA containing the raw POST data, if set to true (1). Otherwise, the variable is populated only when the MIME type of the data is unrecognised.

Comment: Why is this necessary and what does it? This info is missing.

Comment: The PHP always_populate_raw_post_data setting will let PHP always populate the $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA containing the raw POST data, if set to true (1). Otherwise, the variable is populated only when the MIME type of the data is unrecognised.  (Can you please upvote answer if you have downvote recently ?)

Comment: You have to put your comment in your post, otherwise I can't upvote.

Comment: I have already replied to your comment. Check previous comments here.

Comment: You have to put your answer to your post.

Comment: This is my answer already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100462/discussion-between-kishan-patadia-and-black).

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure both your CLI and Web php config files match.

Answer (score 0):

A [sample php.ini](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/php.ini.sample) file is provided in the Magento 2 source. This file is a good guide however these setting should be adjusted for your particular codebase and environment.